# is the threadpool shared - .net

Tags: .net

If i have a webserver running IIS and another application which does a lot of operations using File. class, are the specific threads dedicated to IIS and specific amount for other apps?

Answer (score 2):

A thread belongs to a specific process, it cannot be shared between different processes. This means a thread-pool also belongs to a specific process.

IIS is one process and other apps are their own processes. Each process has its own thread-pool